# Index for MATCH and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM staffs
WHERE MATCH staff_name AGAINST ('johnny')
ORDER BY staff_city ASC
```

Just an example, I want to ask which Index should I use here. For the `MATCH()` and `AGAINST()` there is `FULLTEXT` index on column `staff_name`, that's okay. But in the query there is also `ORDER BY` on the `staff_city` column. The `FULLTEXT` works fast, but when it comes to ordering the matched results, the search is slower. What `INDEX` should need there?

Comment: Anyone here to answer?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can never (almost never) use two indexes in a single `SELECT`.  The Optimizer picks from among the indexes you have, and it *usually* picks the best for the query.

For *this* query, only the `FULLTEXT` index you have will be used, regardless of the other indexes the table has.

The other index might be useful for some *other* query.

**More:**  Assuming you care only about rows with the word 'johnny' in it, change:

```
AGAINST ('johnny')
```

-->

```
AGAINST ('+johnny' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: So what's the solution for faster results for a MATCH and ORDER BY query?

Comment: @YasirM - Use `+` and `IN BOOLEAN MODE` -- if it is appropriate for your search.